# Scrolling in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have been trying to implement scroll bars to scroll through the content of a canvas.

What I have done is basically create a `div` with overflow set to `scroll` for the scroll-bar, and an inner `div` with varying width/height according to the width/height of the content of the canvas.

When I get an `onscroll` event on either of the two scroll-bars, I can use `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties to set how many pixels I need to shift the canvas content.

I noticed that while the vertical scroll-bar was working as intended, changing the inner width of the horizontal scroll-bar was not doing anything.

I was under the impression that something like;

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner'>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
     div#outer {
         width : 500px;
         height : 50px;
         overflow-x : scroll;
     }

     div#inner {
         width : 20000px;
     }
</style>
```

would create a `div` block of width 500px, with a horizontal scroll-bar, allowing us to scroll through the width of the inner `div`, 20000px.

But for some reason it does not work for a horizontal scroll-bar([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8medk/12/)), while working perfectly for a vertical scroll-bar([example](http://jsfiddle.net/tpSgf/1/)).

Why does this happen? Is this something to do with how I am using `style.width` for the inner `div`?

What can I do to get a working horizontal scroll-bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you give a minimum height or add content to the inner element with larger width than the container.

```
bar.style.minHeight = '1px';
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/8medk/13/)

For the reason, my bet is that a block element with no content (`0px` height) is displayed similarly to a `display:none` element.